# BackStackに追加しないとなぜかFragmentの背景が透過されてしまう。

Tags: android, android-fragments

現在作っているアプリには1つのActivityと複数のFragmentがあります。
Fragmentの切り替えはActivityから主に以下のようにして行っています。

```java
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

そして、Androidの戻るキーで前のFragmentへ戻れるようにonBackPressedを以下のように書いています。

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        return;
    }
    finish();
}
```

以下の説明において、FragmentAはWebView・FragmentBはListViewです。
(アプリには他にもFragmentがありますが、今回の説明で不要なので省きます。)
ListViewにも複数のページがあり、何ページへ行っていてもWebViewへ戻れるようにしたいので、
<s>FragmentBは</s>FragmentB_2〜(ListViewの2ページ目以降)はBackStackへ追加しないようにしています。

今回以下のような移動をしたところ、FragmentB_4の背景が透過されて下にFragmentA_3が見えてしまいました。

```
FragmentA_1 遷移→FragmentA_2 遷移→FragmentB_1 遷移→FragmentB_2 遷移→
FragmentB_3 戻る→FragmentA_2 戻る→
FragmentA_1 遷移→FragmentA_3 遷移→FragmentB_4
```

FragmentB_4を表示している時に戻るキーを押すとFragmentA_3が表示されて欲しいのですが、
この状況ですとなぜか押した時にFragmentA_1が表示されます。
FragmentAはWebViewをフルで表示しているからか背景の透過は見られません。

xmlでFragmentBの背景色を指定すると、上の流れでFragmentB_4を表示した時に背景の透過は見られませんが、やはり戻るキーを押すとFragmentA_1が表示されます。

FragmentBをBackStackに追加するようにすれば表示は特に問題はないのですが、
仕様上FragmentBでページ移動した分戻らないとFragmentAが表示されないというのが不便なのでBackStackには追加したくないと考えています。

どうすればやりたいようなことができるでしょうか？

Comment: FragmentManagerで操作しているFragmentはXMLで定義されたものですか？

Comment: 返信遅くなってすみません。 @Shintaro
ここで出てくるFragmentは全て
java右クリック→New→Fragment→Fragment (Blank)
から作成したものです。
FragmentBのxmlにあるLinerLayoutに以下のように書かれています。
`tools:context="jp.co.sakaguchi.FragmentB"`
(パッケージ名やクラス名は実際と異なります。)

"xmlでFragmentBの背景色を指定する"というのは
そのLinerLayoutに背景色を指定した場合のことです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決できたので回答に書きます。

FragmentAをBackStackに追加する時にタグを追加し、
FragmentB_2〜戻る時に`FragmentManager#popBackStack(String,int)`を使うことによってやりたいことができました。